# Doctrine 2.1: How to orderBy aggregate field in a collection?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by, arraycollection

I have an entity with a ArrayCollection field. In the annotations I can write

`@ORM\OrderBy({"somefield" = "DESC"})`

and the collection I get from that entity will be automatically ordered.

My question is if it is possible to order by aggregate fields?

My current issue: I have 2 fields in the collection entity: `visited` and `shown`, I would like to sort the collection by a rating index, which is: `visited / shown`. I tried writting it in the annotations, but it says it should be a valid field. I know how to do this with DQL, but I don't know how to recreate it in the Entity's declaration with annotations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need math operation in ORDER BY statement - in SQL it would be ORDER BY visited/shown DESC. I think it's not possible to do within annotations.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure I do understand your problem. But what does

`@ORM/OrderBy({"visited" = "DESC", "shown" = "DESC"})`

give as result?

From http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby :

> The DQL Snippet in OrderBy is only allowed to consist of unqualified, unquoted field names and of an optional ASC/DESC positional statement. Multiple Fields are separated by a comma (,). The referenced field names have to exist on the targetEntity class of the @ManyToMany or @OneToMany annotation.

Comment: No he need math operation in ORDER BY statement - in SQL it would be `ORDER BY visited/shown DESC`. I think it's not possible to do within annotations

Comment: @MaciejPyszyński You are correct, it's not possible at this point, can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it?